# How do I fire the OnChange event on a lookup field when a new lookup record is created?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I currently have a JavaScript function that runs on the `OnChange()` event of a lookup field. It's working well except for the cases where users have to create a new record for that lookup field. Once they have save the new lookup record, the value of the lookup field has changed but the event has not fired.

Is there a way to force the `OnChange()` event to fire in this case?

**Update 14/8/2015**

It appears that this has occurred as a result of CRM Online 2015 Update 1. When I revert back to using the legacy form rendering, it works fine.

I've raised this as a bug on Microsoft Connect.

Comment: That sounds for me like a bug.

Comment: If you are properly registering the event through the form or the JavaScript api, it should fire even when a new record is created. What mechanism are you using?

Comment: I've registered the event through the form event settings. I will note that I'm using CRM online with the latest update.

Answer (score 0):

Below should work for you:

```
Xrm.Page.getAttribute("lookFieldName").addOnChange(function(){alert('Yoho')});
```